# How do I prevent the creation of multiple Records with an overwritten save button?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, commandbutton

I have a custom save method, which saves my object and redirects me to his parent.
This works fine for me and I used this kind of approach very often.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveAndRedircet}"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {
        PageReference result = null;

        try {
            upsert myObject;

            result = new PageReference('/' + myObject.mdr_Parent__c);
        }
        catch(Exception ignore) {}

        return result;
    }
```

**Question:**

Now I have found a very nasty behavior. If I hit this Save Button multiple times before I get redirected, multiple records of this new object are created.
Multiple objects with the same information are prohibited and normally it is not possible to created them.

How can I prevent this behavior ? That problem doesn't exists with the default save button.
I found a few Javascript hacks, but I don't like this kind of "solutions".

Comment: The answers in [Disable commandButton after first click to prevent double submission](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/disable-commandbutton-after-first-click-to-prevent-double-submission) provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

I would Agree to Lucid's solutions.

Solution1: Render the save button based on this flag i.e set a boolean variable to 'False' as soon as the function is called and render the command button based on this variable.

Solution 2: Write a select query in the function based on a unique ID in the object. If the query returns something, do not insert otherwise insert.
Here's the sample code:

**VF page:**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveAndRedircet}" rendered="{!flag}"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public boolean flag{get;set;}

   public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {

     flag=false;
    PageReference result = null;

    try {
         list<MyObject__c> listMyObj = [Select <fieldNames> from MyObject__c where uniqueID=:your_unique_ID_from_VF_Page];
         if(listMyObj.size()==0)
          insert myObject;
          else
        upsert myObject;

        result = new PageReference('/' + myObject.mdr_Parent__c);
    }
    catch(Exception ignore) {}

    return result;
}
```

This code has both the above solutions implemented. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to set a boolean 'pressed' to true in saveAndRedirect method, and check for it at the top of the method, only continuing if it is false. Alternately, do a SOQL query to see if your object already exists prior to upserting or utilize an externalId with your upsert so that it only updates rather than duplicating.