# apex:commandButton updated by apex:actionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, actionfunction

I am trying to disable my button from being pressed twice.  When this happens, a self-registration user is only created once - but multiple 'account' records are created (person accounts) for each time I was able to speed-click the sign up page.

I previously was using a **facet** to successfully disable the button while the apex was doing its magic.  However, now I have had a change in the process and have to do a second action.  So, I added in actionFunction to daisy-chain them together.  The issue is now I am having the 'duplicates' when I click multiple times.  Is there a way for me to do this with the actionFunction?

What is the proper way to go about disabling this button from being clicked more than once in this situation?  Currently I can set it to disabled, but I can't get it to un-disable after the actions are all finished... thoughts?

```
<apex:commandButton  status="SaveButtonStatus"
                     id="SignUp"
                     onclick="startRegistration_JS();return false;" 
                     value="Sign Up" 
                     reRender="result" />

[action #1]
<apex:actionFunction action="{!startRequest}" 
                     name="startRequest_JS" 
                     reRender="result" 
                     oncomplete="startRegistration_JS() ;"/>
[action #2]        
<apex:actionFunction action="{!startRegistration}" 
                     name="startRegistration_JS" 
                     reRender="result" 
                     oncomplete="status='false';" />
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/disable-commandbutton-after-first-click-to-prevent-double-submission

Comment: I have before... I can't seem to get it working that way, but I'll keep trying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way use action status. Display loading symbol unit your process is not completed.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!startRequest}" 
                     name="startRequest_JS" 
                     reRender="result" 
                     oncomplete="startRegistration_JS() ;"
                     status="counterStatus"/>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!startRegistration}" 
                     name="startRegistration_JS" 
                     reRender="result" 
                     oncomplete="status='false';" 
                     status="counterStatus"/>

<apex:actionstatus id="counterStatus">
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb; height:100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;">
                <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 100px; width: 91px;">
                <img class="waitingImage" src="/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                <span class="waitingDescription">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionstatus>
```

---

### Another way

Below code will work as standard buttons. like when you click on button it will display processing..

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:actionStatus id="mySaveStatus1">
        <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" status="mySaveStatus1" value="Save" disabled="false" rerender="mySaveStatus1"/>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" status="mySaveStatus1" value="Saving..." disabled="true"/> 
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
    <apex:actionStatus id="myCancelStatus1">
        <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" status="myCancelStatus1" value="Cancel" disabled="false" rerender="myCancelStatus1"/>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" status="myCancelStatus1" value="Processing..." disabled="true"/>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use block UI and action status to solve this problem.

```
<apex:actionStatus id="statusSaveTrip" stopText="">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div id="blockUIDiv" >
                    <div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.6; cursor: wait; position: fixed; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
                    <div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1011; position: fixed; padding: 15px; margin: 0px; width: 30%; top: 40%; left: 35%; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: none; cursor: wait; border-radius: 10px; opacity: 0.9; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><img src="/img/loading32.gif"/><br/><h1>Please Wait....</h1></div>
                </div>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
```

Try this code .it will block your screen and you don't need any external Jquery as well.